# Running Clojure REPL Command when a file changes

Tags: clojure, read-eval-print-loop

Every time a source file changes, I'd like to run a command in my currently running running clojure repl. This is similar to people running a bash command upon file changes (i.e., rebuilding their project when a file changes). Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [clojure/tools.namespace](http://clojure/tools.namespace) and its [`clojure.tools.namespace.repl/refresh`](http://clojure.github.io/tools.namespace/#clojure.tools.namespace.repl/refresh) function providing it the `:after` option pointing to your function:

```
(refresh :after 'some-ns/some-fn)
```

From now on `tools.namespace` will watch your source files and reload relevant namespaces if they change and call your function after reloading.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the Prism library. Specifically the [`watch!`](https://github.com/aphyr/prism/blob/9a7a2165d287ab2f929c4a697b0668d7e7126753/src/com/aphyr/prism.clj#L94) function should let you do what you need.